# MySQL two foreign key from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to have two foreign key in table from same table 
example post table has user_id and username from table user

```
--------------------------------
|table user   | table post     |
|-------------|----------------|
|user_id      | post_id        |
|username     | post_title     |
|password     | post_content   |
|email        | user_id     Fk |
|             | username    Fk |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can even have two foreign keys pointing to the same key. For example, post.user_id = user.user_id and post.supervisor_user_id = user.user_id

Comment: Why the tabular format? The two "Columns" have no meaning here...

Comment: Whatever your motivation may be for copying the username value into the post table... you almost certainly shouldn't do it.  You have transitive dependencies among non-prime attributes, which is potentially very problematic.  See [Third Normal Form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically fine.

But keep in mind that the structure listed above could lead to some strange situations.

If a user is allowed to change his own username (which is a separate discussion as to whether that is advisable or not) then you could end up with some scenarios where either a user would not be able to change his name (because then Foreign Key integrity would be broken with a post that refers to his name) or a user could try to hijack another user's posts by changing name to match.

All these problems can be prevented easily enough, but as a general rule I think is better to stick to a single Foreign Key and, generally, to use a number (like user_id) instead of text.

@Alan mentions the idea of two fields in a table referencing the same Foreign Key field of another table - that is quite common and generally OK.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible to use two foreign keys in same table .

But in your case you may not need  'username' as foreign key. because 'user_id' can be used to select username .